# Pass latitude longitude as variable by button to contentpage

Tags: c#, google-maps-api-3, xamarin.forms, azure-web-app-service

I am using webservice via azure, i need to pass latitude and longitude from the db to a contentpage

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with xamarin forms

```
<Button Text="Ver localización" VerticalOptions="Start" Clicked="Onbtn_Clicked"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" /> 


private async void Onbtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
       Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MapAppPage2()) ;
    }
```

In MapAppPage2:

```
map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(latitudeVar, longitudeVar), Distance.FromMiles(10)));
```

I need some guide on how i should proceed, or some document that i could use for help

Comment: Please be more specific about what you need help with.  Is it calling the webservice?  Retrieving values from the db?  Using the geolocation API?  Or just passing data to a new page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass lat / long as parameters to the MapAppPage2.

```
<Button Text="Ver localización" VerticalOptions="Start" Clicked="Onbtn_Clicked"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" /> 


private async void Onbtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
       Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MapAppPage2(lat,long)) ;
    }
```

Then, update your MapAppPage2 Contractor as below.

```
public void MapAppPage2(string _lat, string _long){}
```

Comment: Thanks, i forgot i can edit the constructor and worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

You could do what @Argon mentioned, or you can also store the information and then access it from the storage. Three simple ways to do this-

1. [App Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37266797/how-to-store-app-settings-in-xamarin-forms) - Nothing can be easier
2. [Publisher-subscriber pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) - More professional way of doing it
   Static class with properties - May work depending on your use case. Implement just as mentioned by u/kneticz , but beware that it will break if the app is killed, since the values of the class aren't stored
3. Using a Static class - Shown below:
   I would avoid passing data to views at all costs, it gets unmanageable fast, if you need to tidy for now you could store a class which each of your pages can use as a static class. So create a new file Coordinates:

```
public static class Coordinates()
{
    public static string Longitude {get; set;}
    public static string Latitude {get; set;}
}
```

In the first page you set the values of the static property as shown:

```
Coordinates.Longitude = "86.124124";
Coordinates.Latitude = "25.352552";
```

then in your other page, use get the values of the static property as shown:
var latitude = Coordinates.Latitude;
var longitude = Coordinates.Longitude;
On a side note, you probably want to use a double/float instead of a string.